# Appearing and dissapearing div content by clicking on title

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I know very little about `jQuery`, but I would like to perform something like this in `html`: to have a nested structure

```
<div id="special">
   <div>Some content</div>
   <div>Some content</div>
   <div>Some content</div>
</div>
```

and to give some instructions about `special` so that the content inside does not appear immediately, but only after clicking on the title, and that dissapears again if the title is clicked again. It would be nice to have an effect like the one in [accordion](http://jqueryui.com/accordion/), but the point is to have the same result not clicking another box, but the same box.

I suppose it must be done somewhere, but I just do not know the suitable key word. Any idea or reference to a done example will be very helpful and welcome.

Comment: Don't search anyfurther, you exactly need : http://jqueryui.com/accordion/. Documentation is well made, and provide an example which feets your need.

Comment: which one is the `title` here? use could use `slideToggle`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HTML**

```
<button class="title">Title</button>
<div id="special">
   <div>Some content</div>
   <div>Some content</div>
   <div>Some content</div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('.title').click(function() {
    $('#special').toggle('slow');
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/EwNRJ/2001/)**

Answer (score 2):

Here is a simple way to do the same. i have added an additional head element inside special that toggles the row elements

```js
$(function() {
  $("#head").click(function() {
    $(this).nextAll('.row').toggleClass('visible');
  });
});
```

```css
#special {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: table;
}
#head {
  height: 10px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: table-row;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.row {
  display: none;
}
.visible {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="special">
  <div id="head">Header</div>
  <div class="row">Some content</div>
  <div class="row">Some content</div>
  <div class="row">Some content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I get it right, but here is my suggestion:

**Javascript**

```
$('h1').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next('div').slideToggle();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<h1>Special</h1>
<div id="special">
   <div>Some content</div>
   <div>Some content</div>
   <div>Some content</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#special{
    display: none;
}
```

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/779poffz/)

Answer (score 0):

You *could* do this in pure CSS also. Might look like:

```
div#special {
  height: 20px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}

div#special:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: 'click me!';
  color: white;
}

div#special:focus:before {
  display: none;
}

div#special:focus {
  background-color: transparent;
}

div#special > div {
  display: none;
}

div#special:focus > div {
   display: block;
}
```

But you would need to modify your HTML slightly as well, we need a `tabIndex` for this to work

```
<div id="special" tabIndex="1">
   <div>Some content</div>
   <div>Some content</div>
   <div>Some content</div>
</div>
```

**demo**: http://jsbin.com/zatevunewo/1/edit?html,css,output

Comment: Could you give me some demo, like the other ones? I am not used to imagine the effects just from reading the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="special" style="width:200px;height:200px;background:green;">
   <div id="special1" style="width:200px;height:20px;background:red;">Some content</div>
   <div>Some content</div>
   <div>Some content</div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#special").click(function(){
        $("#special1").toggle();
});
</script>
```

Click anywhere on the div `#special`... `#special1` appears and disappers on next click..